# Await data from promise inside if statement VUE

Tags: javascript, vue.js, promise, vue-component

I have this login function, where I inside want to give my session some data I can use later on.

The problem is when I want to push the data to my session I get from a promise it tries to put the data in before I get the result from my promise.

Here is my promise:

```
async setData (storeId) {
      var getData = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        let data = Functions.getScore('day', storeId)
        data.then(function (result) {
          resolve(result)
        })
      })
      getData.then(function (result) {
        console.log(result)
        return result
      })
```

here is my login function

```
login () {
      axios.post('API', {
        username: this.username,
        password: this.password,
        'condition': 'dashboard'
      }).then(response => {
        if (!response.data.Error) {
          var storeId = response.data.accessId
          this.$session.start()
          this.account = response.data
          // here do i want to store the data.
          this.$session.set('store', this.setData(storeId)) 
          this.$session.set('user', response.data)
          console.log(this.$session.getAll())
          //i will get my result here AFTER it should have filled the session 
        } else {
          alert('something went wrong')
        }
      })
     }
```

I have tried to put await into my if function, but it says await is a reserved word

[image: promise]

As you can see here it gives me the result after I try to put i into session.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an async handler `.then(async response => {})`

```
login () {
  axios.post('API', {
    username: this.username,
    password: this.password,
    'condition': 'dashboard'
  }).then(async response => {
    if (!response.data.Error) {
      var storeId = response.data.accessId
      this.$session.start()
      this.account = response.data
      // here do i want to store the data.
      const storeData = await this.setData(storeId)
      this.$session.set('store', storeData) 
      this.$session.set('user', response.data)
      console.log(this.$session.getAll())
      //i will get my result here AFTER it should have filled the session 
    } else {
      alert('something went wrong')
    }
  })
 }
```